# An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when attempting to run 's3 mb' command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm new to using AWS & I'm running into a very persistent error.

```
make_bucket failed: s3://bucket-name An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

I honestly have no idea why this error pops up. I have given my EC2 instance full access to S3, so I should have the permission to create new buckets in S3.

I ran the command:

```
aws s3 mb s3://bucket-name
```

and I kept on running it and getting this same error.

I tried to run this command instead:

```
aws s3 mb s3://bucket-name --region us-east-1
```

and I STILL kept on getting this error.

I'm stuck here and I'd appreciate any assistance I can get :)

Comment: What if you use [aws s3api create-bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html) command?

Comment: [aws s3 mb fails due to IllegalLocationConstraintException · Issue #3567 · aws/aws-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3567) suggests that it might be an error associated with the bucket name. Can you try it with another simple bucket name, eg `aws s3 mb s3://moataz9378`?

Comment: That error is almost always caused because the bucket name you've selected already exists.

Comment: You're right m8 :) its about the bucket naming

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It was the bucket name. Apparently it has to be unique in the sense that no other bucket can exist with the same name.