# Boto3 Exception when Creating s3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to create a bucket using:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id=api_id,
                         aws_secret_access_key=apikey,
                         region_name='us-east-1')

bucket_name = 'test1'

s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

I've seen this same code everywhere all over SO and Github and it's meant to work but I'm getting this exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

Which from my research means I should specify the region (I did so in the client here), I also tried this line (using `us-east-2` just to test a different region):

```
s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'})
```

But that still throws an exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The us-east-2 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

I also tried this code:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id=api_id,
                         aws_secret_access_key=apikey)

bucket_name = 'test1'

s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

And my .aws config file specified:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

As far as I can tell, one of these methods should have worked. If it were an auth issue, I'd have gotten that exception instead.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems like the bucket name you are trying to create is already created. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73562686/an-error-occurred-illegallocationconstraintexception-when-attempting-to-run-s

Comment: Your code example does not look like the one in the Code Library. As specified in my answer, this is the location you should use to get the latest code examples when using any AWS SDK.  Furthermore - be sure to follow the Readme that the code lib refers to in order to set up your Dev Environment - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/README.md#Prerequisites

Answer (score 1):

When your code runs, it sends requests to an AWS endpoint in the desired Region.

Since your configuration file has `region = us-east-1`, the request is being sent to the North Virginia region.

Amazon S3 in that region can *only* create buckets in 'itself' (`us-east-1`). Therefore, you either need to specify `{'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'}` *OR* you need to connect to Amazon S3 in the region where you want to create the bucket:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
```

Simply put, the region you are connecting to must match the `LocationConstraint` when creating an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer but the code examples I included were each run individually so when I ran the second longer snippet which doesn't specify a region either in the client or in the create command, it should pick up the region from the config file which is us-east-1 (I believe...). So it DOES work on us-east-2 but just not us-east-1. Is there a safeguard with programmtically accessing us-east-1?

Comment: The region from the config file will default the target Region used for API calls. It is separate to the `LocationConstraint` field, which defines in which region you would like to create the bucket. If the two match, their should be no error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message displayed by the boto3 client is misleading, the error is actually due to the bucket name that you specified not being globally unique. Every bucket that is created has to have a unique name.
Try doing the same but use a longer, more complex bucket name which is unlikely to collide with any existing bucket names.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) that has the latest SDK examples for Python. All code examples you find in this doc have been tested many times and work.

This is the document to refer to for finding AWS SDK code examples and contain the latest code examples.

See this topic:

[Create an Amazon S3 bucket using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_CreateBucket_section.html)

This example includes many different SDK examples including Python.

Comment: This gives me the same error but all of these answers work if I change the region to us-east-2 which makes me think there's some sort of programmatic safeguard with defaulting to us-east-1.

Answer (score -1):

It works as long as I don't try to write into us-east-1, any of the other regions work just fine.